# Why fundamental type int x gets initialized if a vector member is present in a class?

Tags: c++, class, vector, integer, c++17

If I replace the vector member by another fundamental type variable (such as int y for example), x doesnt get initialized, as expected. What does the vector member does to member x, that makes x gets initialized even though it is not initialized at declaration and fundamental types are not supposed to initialized upon creation?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Buffer
{
private:
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    int x;
public:
    Buffer(int width, int height) // buffer gets initialized to size 0, and x gets initialized to 0
    {
        buffer.resize(width * height); // buffer gets resized to argument values
    }
};


int main()
{
    Buffer screen_2(10,10); // member x get initialized to 0

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just because `x` happens to be 0 doesn't mean it's been initialised

Comment: Since the constructor of `Buffer` does not initialise `x`, the member `x` of `screen_2` is uninitialised.    Accessing its value gives undefined behaviour.   One possibility, within the realm of undefined behaviour, is that `x` is initialised with a value of zero.  That is not, however, guaranteed to happen.    This also means that testing (in your case, presumably examining the value of `screen_2.x` using a debugger, or accessing it using code you haven't shown) is not definitive.   You observing a value of zero does not mean the member is initialised to zero.

Comment: @Peter, thanks. The thing is that before entering the constructor x has a random value (I am using the debugger VS2019, Win 10) and right after entering it changes to 0. The other thing is that when I replace the vector for another int, before entering the buffer constructor x has a random value, and after entering it remains with the random value. That difference in the behavior makes me say that x gets initialized. Now, after telling you this, you still say that even though the value of x gets changed from a random value to zero, THAT  is considered as undefined behavior? (thanks again)

Comment: That's strange. VS in Debug mode should fill uninitialised bytes with predefined values like 0xCC. Make sure to set configuration to Debug.

Comment: It is in debug mode, the value of x before entering the constructor is: -858993460 or cccccccc in memory. after entering the constructor it gets changed to 0. Funny thing, before entering the constructor the value of x and the vector have different memorry adreess than after entering the constructor. Maybe it has something to do that vector allocates memory and the adress of variable x gets changed, thus also the value?

Comment: what i meant to say is, the configuration is set to debug.

Comment: @WalterS.Escobedo -  The member remains uninitialised according to the standard.   There is nothing to prevent an implementation (e.g. a compiler) from actually initialising the member. But one compiler could initialise it to zero. Another compiler could initialise it to `42`. Another could do nothing, and the value corresponds to whatever the physical bytes in memory happened to hold at the time. All of those compilers would be correct, from the perspective of the standard.  (Remember - the standard is the yardstick for assessing correctness of implementations, not the reverse).

Comment: @Peter thanks man, your answer makes sense to me. I'll try to stick to the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is uninitialized. Reading from it causes undefined behavior, which can have any effect, including giving you `0` every time.

You can inspect the generated assembly to know what exactly is going on, but I don't see much value in it.

Comment: I was thinking that in absence of a constructor every uninitialized member is guaranteed to get the default value for it , namely zero. Am I wrong?

Comment: @newbie *"in absence of a constructor"* OP does have a constructor. You might be thinking about rule concerning *default* constructors, which says that if a default constructor is either implicitly generated or marked as `=default` in the class body, then value-initializing the class (i.e. using `{}` or `()`, with nothing inside of them) will zero the fields that would otherwise be uninitialized. But OP's class doesn't have a default constructor to begin with, so this doesn't apply.